# ebean define foreign key as primary key or better unique constraint?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, jpa-2.0, primary-key, ebean

I am currently implementing a rating system for a webshop with Play 2.2.1. Play uses Ebean as ORM. In the shop every rated product has an average rating.
So I created two Models:

Product:

```
@Entity
public class Product extends Model {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_seq")
  public Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product")
  public AverageRating averageRating;
  ...
}
```

AverageRating:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "product_id"))
public class AverageRating extends Model {

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
  public Product product; 
  ...
}
```

The one-to-one relation should be bidirectional and the ownig model is AverageRating. 
My generated table for AverageRating looks like this:

```
create table average_rating (
product_id                bigint,
average_grade             float,
...    
constraint uq_average_rating_1 unique (product_id));

alter table average_rating add constraint fk_average_rating_product_1 foreign key
(product_id) references product (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
```

My question: I'd rather define the foreign product_id as primary key in average_rating than using an unique constraint. Or am I completely wrong and should better use separate id as primary key and keep the unique constraint on product_id? If a product will be deleted I can define a cascade so the corresponding row in average_rating will be deleted as well. So I don't see any reason for a seperate id. 
If the idea with foreign key as primary key sounds good, how will the mapping look like? If I use

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="product_id")    
public Product product;
```

in AverageRating, all attributes of product will be joined to my average_rating table...

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Sadly, using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn it is not possible. See https://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/jpa/